# Let std::vector take the ownership from a raw pointer

Tags: stdvector

I have a passed in unmanaged buffer with a type like this `BYTE*`, so this is a byte buffer and length information is also known, and now I want to use byte buffer to create a vector like this `std::vector<BYTE>`,

I know I could use copy and manually delete this buffer later like following,

```
foo(BYTE* in, int size) {
    ...
    std::vector<BYTE> vec;
    std::copy(in, in + size, std::back_inserter(vec));
    ...
}
```

My question is what is the best way to avoid a copy here? I feel there should be a good way to create this vector so that this vector takes ownership of this buffer using given pointer, aside from avoid a copy, another advantage is that I don't have to manually `delete` this buffer after copy. I think there is definitely some elegant way to do this safely.

Comment: I don't think you can, since I think `std::vector` is allowed to require additional memory beside the actual storage of the objects. Could you possibly just stick the pointer into a `std::unique_ptr<BYTE[]>` (with appropriate deleter?).

Comment: Thanks for reply, I decided to follow the suggestion you gave by using `std::unique_ptr`.